# Automatically add and remove files in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a particular folder in my project directory for which I would like to always hold in my Subversion repository, on each particular commit, the files that were in the folder at the time.

As they change very frequently it seems a real bother to have to delete them from the repository and also add new ones each time.  (I use TortoiseSVN).

Is there anyway I can set things up so that in this one folder, all files are added to and removed from the current version as they are added and removed from the folder locally.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Don

Comment: Your question in not obvious

Comment: the files update? or new ones (with different names) get created?  automatically checking in would generally be a bad thing.  what are you working on/with?

Comment: Are they binary files? Why this need to add and delete them each commit?